# E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

9

I am facing this issue while I run my android app. Does anyone know about this issue and how to fix it?

I am facing this issue in my Logcat while I run my android app. Does anyone know about this issue and how to fix it?

The app dones't crash, but when I select option in spinner and click on button then it will not show result on google map

MainActivity.Java

```
package com.example.nearbyplacedemo;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.AsyncQueryHandler;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //initialize variable
    Spinner sp_type;
    Button bt_find;
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;
    GoogleMap map;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    double currentLat = 0, currentLong = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Assign Variable
        sp_type = findViewById(R.id.sp_type);
        bt_find = findViewById(R.id.bt_find);
        supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);

        //Initialize Array of place list
        String[] placeTypeList = {"hospital", "medical", "atm"};
        //Initialize Array of Place name list
        String[] placeNameList = {"Hospital", "Medical", "ATM"};

        //set Adapter on Spinner
        sp_type.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, placeNameList));

        //Initialize Fused location client
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        //check permission
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //if permission is granted
            //call method
            getCurrentLocation();
        } else {
            //when permission denied
            //request permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 44);

        }
        bt_find.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //get selected position of spinner
                int i = sp_type.getSelectedItemPosition();
                //Initialize Url
                String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json" +//Url
                        "?location=" + currentLat + "," + currentLong +//location latitude and longitude
                        "&radius=5000" +//nearby Radius
                        "&type" + placeTypeList[i] +//place type
                        "&sensor = true" +//Sensor
                        "&key=" + "AIzaSyCEidC6oECzj0IexspcvUpqnKPS2_nhKfQ";

                //execute place task method to download json data
                new Placetask().execute(url);
            }
        });


    }

    private void getCurrentLocation() {
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this , Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                (this , Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},44);
            return;
        }

        //Initailize task location
        Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                //when successs
                if(location!=null){
                    //when location is not null
                    //get current latitude
                    currentLat = location.getLatitude();
                    //get current longitude
                    currentLong = location.getLongitude();
                    //sync map
                    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
                            //when map is ready
                            map = googleMap;
                            //zoom on current location
                            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(currentLat,currentLong),14));

                        }
                    });

                }

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode==44){
            if (grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                //when permission is granted
                //call methode
                getCurrentLocation();
            }
        }
    }

    private class Placetask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String data ;
            try {
                //Initialize data
                data=downloadUrl(strings[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            //Excute parser task
            new ParserTask().execute(s);
        }
    }

    private String downloadUrl(String string) throws IOException {
        //Initialize Url
        URL url = new URL(string);
        //Initialize connection
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        //connect connection
        connection.connect();
        //initialize inputstream
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        //Initialize bufferreader
        BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        //Initialize string builder
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        //Initailize String variable
        String line = "";
        //use while loop
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
            //append line
            builder.append(line);

        }
        //get append data
        String data = builder.toString();
        //close reader
        reader.close();
        //return data
        return data;


    }

    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>> {
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... strings) {
           //create jason parser
            JsonPaeser jsonPaeser = new JsonPaeser();
             //Initialize hash map list
            List<HashMap<String,String>> mapList=null;
            JSONObject object ;
            try {
                //intialize jsonobject
                object = new JSONObject(strings[0]);
                //Parse jsonobject
                mapList = jsonPaeser.parseResult(object);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            //return map list
            return mapList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> hashMaps) {
            if (map != null) {
                map.clear();
            } else {
                // Handle the case when the GoogleMap object is null
                Log.e("GoogleMap", "GoogleMap object is null");
            }

            //clear map
           // map.clear();
            //use for loop
            for (int i=0;i<hashMaps.size();i++){
                //initialize hashmap
                HashMap<String,String> hashMapList = hashMaps.get(i);
                //get latitude
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(hashMapList.get("lat"));
                //get longitude
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(hashMapList.get("lng"));
                //get name
                String name = hashMapList.get("name");
                //concat latitude longitude
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat,lng);
                //Initialize Marker Option
                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
                //set position
                options.position(latLng);
                //set title
                options.title(name);
                //add marker option
                map.addMarker(options);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

JsonParser.java:-

```
package com.example.nearbyplacedemo;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import  java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonPaeser {
    private HashMap<String , String> parseJsonObject(JSONObject object){
        //initialize hashmap
        HashMap<String,String> datalist = new HashMap<>();
        //get name form object
        try {
            String name = object.getString("name");
            //get latitude from object
            String latitude = object.getJSONObject("geometery")
                    .getJSONObject("location").getString("lat");
            //get longitude from object
            String longitude = object.getJSONObject("geometery")
                    .getJSONObject("location").getString("lng");
            //put all value in hashmap
            datalist.put("name",name);
            datalist.put("lat",latitude);
            datalist.put("lng",longitude);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return datalist;

    }
    private List<HashMap<String,String>> parseJsonArray(JSONArray jsonArray){
        //Initialize hashmap list
        List<HashMap<String,String>> datalist= new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            try {
                //Initialize Hashmap
                HashMap<String,String> data = parseJsonObject((JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i));
                //add data in hashmap
                datalist.add(data);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        //retuen hashmap list
        return datalist;
    }
    public List<HashMap<String,String>> parseResult(JSONObject object){
        //initialize jsonArray
        JSONArray jsonArray ;

        try {
            //get result array
            jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("results");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        //return array
        return parseJsonArray(jsonArray);

    }
}
```

I Build Android App in which find user current location and the if user want nearby hospital, medical, atm then it select and the app show result. but in my app app run successfully but at the time user enter input app show error in logcat and don't show result